# How to make a rolling upgrade with ansible in a different AWS VPC subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, continuous-deployment

We are running a continuous integration server (jenkins) in a public subnet of our AWS VPC, and we'd like to trigger an upgrade as a post build task when a commit is made to `master`...

The easiest way would be to let ansible to ssh-in the machines, pull the latest `master` and restart the service, then proceed to the next one; but since the CI host is running in a different subnet we cannot reach the servers.

Our autoscaling configuration user data script fetches the `HEAD` of the repository automatically upon start, so all we'd need to do is terminate all the existing instances in the ELB all let autoscaling to bring up the new ones.

The problem is that I don't know how to specify in the playbook that it should wait until a new instance is up and running before terminating the next one.

Another option that would work is to bring up all the new instances at once and when they are up and running detach from the ELB and terminate all the old ones (but I cannot find examples about how to do that either!).

Comment: Do you want it all hands-off fully automated?

Comment: yeah, we'd like to make it automatically in the CI server whenever a commit is pushed to a certain branch

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a new autoscale group with a new ELB and all new instances. When they're launched you can run tests against the new ELB, confirm everything is working, then swing DNS over. The gotcha with this approach is around ELB pre-warming. If your site is busy the new ELB will not handle the traffic unless you ask Amazon to "prewarm" it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a server has started or shutdown you can do this from your Jenkins server, although it needs to be able to reach your instances inside your VPC.

```
---
name: Deployment playbook
hosts: all

tasks:
  # Using port 2222 here but you can use port 80 or 443
  - name: Wait for new deployment instance to come up.
    local_action: wait_for host=your_new_deployment_host port=2222

  - name: Shutdown or terminate old servers
    local_action: command ec2-terminate-instances <your-old-server-instance-id>
```

To get around the VPC issue you can probably setup an ssh tunnel from  **your server** at startup to your Jenkins server (public IP) like this:

```
ssh -f -N -R2222:localhost:22  jenkins@yourjenkinsserver.com -S /tmp/control-socket
```

and if you want to check for http in Jenkins on port 8888

```
ssh -f -N -R8888:localhost:80  jenkins@yourjenkinsserver.com -S /tmp/control-socket-http
```

The trick here is that you need to bring up the new servers sequentially because you are always using the same port 8888 on the Jenkins server to check. Also you need to terminate the tunnels after you've done the check. From your Jenkins server:

```
name: Terminate tunnel HTTP
local_action: shell ssh -p 2222 localhost 'ssh -S /tmp/control-socket-http -O exit yourjenkinsserver.com'

name: Terminate tunnel SSH
local_action: shell ssh -p 2222 localhost 'ssh -S /tmp/control-socket -O exit yourjenkinsserver.com'
```

A lot of moving pieces but should do the trick.